# htmlentities() double encoding entities in string

Tags: php

I want only the unencoded characters to get converted to html entities, without affecting the entities which are already present. I have a string that has previously encoded entities, e.g.:

```
gaIUSHIUGhj>&hyphen; hjb&times;jkn.jhuh>hh> &hellip;
```

When I use `htmlentities()`, the `&` at the beginning of entities gets encoded again. This means `&hyphen;` and other entities have their `&` encoded to `&amp;`:

```
&amp;times;
```

I tried decoding the complete string, then encoding it again, but it does not seem to work properly. This is the code I tried:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
...

$b = 'gaIUSHIUGhj>&hyphen; hjb&times;jkn.jhuh>hh> &hellip;';
$b = html_entity_decode($b, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$b = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $b);
$b = htmlentities($b, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

But it does not seem to work the right way. Is there a way to prevent or stop this from happening?

Answer (score 6):

Set the optional `$double_encode` variable to `false`. See the [documentation](http://php.net/htmlentities) for more information.

Your resulting code should look like:

```
$b = htmlentities($b, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Answer (score 5):

You did good looking at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), but you missed the best part. It can be hard to decipher this sometimes:

```
//     >    >    >    >    >    >    Scroll    >>>    >    >    >    >    >     Keep going.    >    >    >    >>>>>>  See below.  <<<<<<
string htmlentities ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $encoding = 'UTF-8' [, bool $double_encode = true ]]] )
```

<sup>*Look at the very end.*</sup>

I know. *Confusing.* I usually ignore the signature line and go straight down to the next block (***`Parameters`***) for the blurbs on each argument.

So you want to use the ***`double_encoded`*** argument at the end to tell `htmlentities` not to re-encode (and you probably want to stick with `UTF-8` unless you have a specific reason not to):

```
$str = "gaIUSHIUGhj>&hyphen; hjb&times;jkn.jhuh>hh> &hellip;";

// Double-encoded!
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8', true) . "\n";

// Not double-encoded!
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8', false);
```

https://ignite.io/code/513ab23bec221e4837000000